# Hibernate Request processing failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am inserting user which hv many-to-one mapping to city. And then City hv manytone mapping to Country. So, when i insert user with duplicate city or country, it throws exception.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2095697913583686677L;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String dob;
    private long mobile;
    private String email;
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_name", nullable = false)
    private City city;
    private String country;
    private String password;
    private Date createdTime;
    private Date lastLoggedIn;
    private int rating;
    @Id
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public long getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(long mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getCreatedTime() {
        return createdTime;
    }

    public void setCreatedTime(Date createdTime) {
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }

    public Date getLastLoggedIn() {
        return lastLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setLastLoggedIn(Date lastLoggedIn) {
        this.lastLoggedIn = lastLoggedIn;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name = " + firstname + ",Mobile = " + mobile + ",Email = "
                + email + ",City = " + city + ",Country = " + country
                + ", TimeCreated = " + createdTime;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "city_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String cityName;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_name", nullable = false)
    private Country countryName;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_name")
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getStockDailyRecords() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public Country getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(Country countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "country_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String countryName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_name")
    private List<City> citys;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public List<City> getCitys() {
        return citys;
    }

    public void setCitys(List<City> citys) {
        this.citys = citys;
    }

}
```

`Hibernate Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.shubh.model.User.city -> com.shubh.model.City; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

spring configuration :-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shubh" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="mysqldataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"> -->
<!--        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apu"></property> -->
<!--        <property name="user" value="root"></property> -->
<!--        <property name="password" value="admin"></property> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.shubh.model" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apu" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="admin" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven />

   <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.shubh.repository"/>



</beans>
```

Comment: Your error message is saying otherwise (I believe). It seems that you are not persisting your DAO correctly. Also, how are you configuring your persistence.xml and applicationContext.xml files? Can you please post them?

Comment: i have User entity which have many-to-one mapping with city. Then City entity have many-to-one mapping with country. So if i insert user with same city and country, it gives me this error.

Comment: @SubhamRohatgi       Nevertheless, post your spring applicationContext.xml and persistence.xml files in this question. It's a standard practice to put your persistence and context settings file with a question when you have tagged it with `spring`

Comment: Change `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>` to `create` not `update`. It's funny how 'validate' should work with a a database in testing and also in production, but it doesn't

Comment: in this case , it will drop the table and create again everytime i restart my server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code saving your objects.. But from the exception stack i can see that you are trying to save person before you save city.

Comment: i m trying to save country then city and then user. The cityName and countryName are unique.  When i m trying to save other user from same city and country, i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient.`

it comes when you are trying to persist parent object and your child is not yes persisted, so in your case please save first country, city and then set it to user object and then save the user object.

there are multiple methods to save object in hibernate depends on which you are using

```
saveOrUpdate();
update();
save();
persist();
merge();
```

for more detail please visit http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-save-vs-saveorupdate-vs-persist-vs-merge-vs-update-explanation-with-examples